# Make the user 'like' my app. when granting permissions in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there any method available in JS SDK to do so? I would like to make the users 'like' my app. automatically, so i can send PMs later

Comment: Make a great app, and I'm sure the user will "like" it eventually ;-)

Comment: I can promise you that if I used an app which automatically liked itself for me I'd delete/ban it from my account in about .03 seconds. I suspect a lot of people would feel that way too.

Comment: yeah! i too feel the same way but i cant seem to find a way to message a targeted user. Is there any way?

Comment: You might want to re-phrase the question to make that the primary question then: "How can I direct-message a Facebook user from my app" Also, include a bit of background so people can better help out. (I don't know the Facebook API)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible and I doubt it ever will be able, forcing a user to do anything like this is highly frowned upon and is probably in breach of Facebook policy.

You can however use the API to like certain objects such as posts, photos and videos.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible (and should not be possible) as this would be doing something without the knowledge of the user.

Comment: Can i send messages if i make them my friends?

Comment: I think that if users add your app then your app can send them messages. Check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can send "messages" to all or some users with server-side requests like those http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/